# How do I move this image/link in css

Tags: javascript, css

Im trying to move this image in css but it just wont move no mater how many times I test it, what am I doing wrong?

```css
#yahoo1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 800px;
}
```

```html
<p id="yahoo1">
  <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">
    <img border="0" alt="yahoo" src="images/yahoo.png" width="300" height="300">
  </a>
</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _move this image links_?

Comment: Explain clearly..

Comment: Move from where to where?

Comment: typo, I meant to type image link* it's an image that when you click on it, goes to a website (yahoo)

Comment: It is working fine if you want to open link in new tab write target="_blank" in your anchor tag, yes it is not working in jsfiddle but it is working in browser

Answer (score 0):

```
#yahoo1 {
  position: relative;
}

#yahoo1 a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 800px;
}

#yahoo1 img {
  display: block;
}
```